# Why is AppWidgetProvider created each time I add an app widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I'm slighty puzzled about how android's AppWidget machinery works.

I reimplemented the AppWidgetProvider's constructor like this:

```
public class MyProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

   public MyProvider() {
     Log.d("TEST", "Creating...")
   }

   public void onUpdate(..., int[] appWidgetIds) {
      // updating stuff here
   } 
}
```

From what I've read in the docs, I understood that AppWidgetProvider is instantiated once, when widget of that type is added for the first time. If another widget of the **same** type gets added, it will be managed by exactly that provider.

But I just discovered that this is not the case!

For each widget I add, android creates a new MyProvider (I see that from 'adb logcat' - it prints "Creating..." for each widget)!
I don't understad why :)
Maybe I got something wrong? Or documentation isn't clear on something.
What's the reason of having appWidgetIds passed to *onUpdate* and other methods if each provider is managing only ONE widget?

Comment: I believe the AppWidgetManager is instantiated once, the AppWidgetProvider would be created for each instance of the widget that is added. Where in the docs do you see that the app widget provider is only created once, i can't find that info in there?

Comment: I just assumed that because I saw appWidgetIds argument :)
I thought "what's the point of having it if it would always be equal to 1".
Thank you. Also see the answers below, guys are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`. Quoting the [`BroadcastReceiver` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only
>   valid for the duration of the call to
>   onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your
>   code returns from this function, the
>   system considers the object to be
>   finished and no longer active.

Hence, `AppWidgetProviders` are disposable and should be treated as such. Every app widget operation (update, etc.) will result in a provider being created, used, and discarded.

Answer (score 0):

[AppWidgetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getInstance%28android.content.Context%29) is created only once. An [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) is created for each AppWidget that is created.